# Generics data type creation is unchecked or unsafe operations

Tags: java, generics

I was trying to create a new data type with generics but the javac compiler keeps telling me

```
"Note: MyStack.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
, when I try to recompile it with the option -Xlint, 
"MyStack.java:8: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
        data = (T[]) new Object[5];
                 ^
  required: T[]
  found:    Object[]
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class MyStack
1 warning
```

. What should I do to avoid this warning?

```
public class MyStack<T> {

    int index;
    private T[] data;

    public MyStack() {
        index = 0;
        data = (T[]) new Object[5];
    }

    public void push(T input) {
        data[index++] = input;
    }

    public T pop() {
        return data[--index];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array has a distinct type at runtime.  If you create an array of Object, that is its permanent runtime type:

```
Object[] data = new Object[5];
System.out.println(data.getClass());    // Prints class [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

- If you create an array of String, the array’s permanent runtime type is `[Ljava.lang.String;`.
- If you create an array of int, the array’s permanent runtime type is `[I`.

And so on.

Generic types do not exist at runtime.  They are a type safety mechanism enforced entirely by the compiler.  This means there is no `T` at runtime, which means it is not possible to compile `T[]` because the compiler cannot generate code that creates a specific, known array type.

What can you do about it?  Normally, you would use a Collection class, like ArrayList, but I’m guessing your assignment doesn’t allow that.

One way to enforce generics at runtime is by keeping a [Class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html) object in each MyStack instance.

```
public class MyStack<T> {

    int index;
    private Object[] data;
    private final Class<T> elementType;

    public MyStack(Class<T> elementType) {
        this.elementType = elementType;
        index = 0;
        data = new Object[5];
    }
```

You can then use the [cast](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29) method to provide type safety in the `pop` method:

```
public T pop() {
    return elementType.cast(data[--index]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not way to avoid warning. In this [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java) we can see a solution using Array.newInstance(class, size). But we should add annotation '@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")' to deal with it.

Also, if you are not do programming exercise or do a framework / library. I recommend you to use the java.collection data structures.

I Hope I helped you